# Ansible - template keys and values exactly as they are

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have this variable, which I template, using the template module:

```yaml
my_var: 
  something_else: 
    oh_yeah: 
      i_am_noob: true
  value_1: 
    enabled: true
```

Example of desired output on target machine:

```yaml
# note the indenting, that is desired
  something_else: 
    oh_yeah: 
      i_am_noob: true
  value_1: 
    enabled: true
```

I have tried configuring my template file as follows:

```yaml
  {{ my_var | to_nice_yaml }}
```

However, that did not provide the desired output, the indenting/outdenting is messed up.

I assume I have to use some 'pretty' filter or 'raw', or use something along the lines of `for key, value in value_1.items()`. Tried those as well, did not work.

**Q:** How can I configure Ansible so that it templates the keys and values 1:1 to the target?

Comment: You're calling `to_nice_yaml`, but the example you've shown is *not* valid YAML. I don't think Ansible could even parse that without errors. Can you show us a runnable playbook that reproduces the problem?

Comment: What do you mean? It parses. Perhaps you've set it up incorrectly, or misread my question. It's a bit harsh to vote for a close when you might be then one in the wrong.

Comment: The variable *my_var* is not valid YAML. The indentations of the attributes *MYVAR* and *i_am_here* are wrong. Use, for example, [YAML Lint](http://www.yamllint.com/) to test it.

Comment: I see, I've edited my question. Noobie mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [`indent()` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.indent) when you need your output to have extra leading indentation.

```
{{ my_var | to_nice_yaml | indent(width=2, first=True) }}
```

Comment: You may also want to add `first=true` to also indent the first line - default is false

Comment: I got it, finally. `{{ my_var | to_nice_yaml(indent=2) | indent(width=2, first=True) }}`

Comment: Sorry, I misremembered what the indent parameter does. I have updated the answer to point to the correct filter.